# How to parse JSON subitem

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

this is the response data that I'm getting.
Can someone know how to parse this data?

```
"message":{
       "amount":{"notFloat":"'asd' does not appear to be a float"},
       "lastname":{"notEmpty"}:"lastname must be required"},
       etc....
 }
```

What I want is to display all detected error in organize format.

```
options.save(d, {
                success: function (model, response) {
                    if(response['status'] == 'success'){
                        alert = new AlertView({type: 'success', message: 'New record successfully added.'}); 
                    } else {
                         alert = new AlertView({type: 'error', message: response['message']});
                    }
                    alert.render();
                },
                error: function (model, response) {
                    alert = new AlertView({type: 'error', message: response});
                    alert.render();
                }
            });
```

Comment: this is Invalid Json, check using jsonlint.com

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Check the code which is generating the response.

Comment: this is the response from my API.

Comment: What language your using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = $.parseJSON(jsonAsTextFromServer);
$.each( data.message, function( key, value ) {
    $.each( value, function( err_key, err_value ) {
        alert( key + "::" + err_key + ": " + err_value );
    });

});
```

BTW this response is malformed. It should be wrapped by { }

[DEMO (Updated)](http://jsfiddle.net/4Yz4f/1/)

Comment: actually this is looks like: {"status":"error","message":{"amount":{"notFloat":"'asd' does not appear to be a float"}}}..